# What are some ways to get a list of DateTime.Now.AddDays(0..7) dynamically?

Tags: c#, .net, optimization, performance

The most efficient and typical solution that I could think of is:

```
var dates = new DateTime[7];
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
  dates[i] = DateTime.Now.AddDays(i);
```

This will return me seven (7) dates in an array, which is the result I want. I *think* ruby can do something like this, simply by specifying dots but I can't recall.

However, is there a more efficient approach? Or is there any way to implement this using linq (possibly via the `Aggregate` method?), if there is, even if it is not the most efficient solution I would be curious to see.

Ideally it would not require you to re-declare any object instance for the amount of "times" you need though, and allow you to specify `DateTime.Now` just once and the number of items in the array/list you want just once.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would use [`Enumerable.Range`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range.aspx), which is very handy when it comes to generating sequences of data:

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
var dates = Enumerable.Range(0, 7).Select(n => now.AddDays(n)).ToArray();
```

Comment: Now that's sexy, thanks. I will see what other answers I get before accepting yours; however I really like it.

Comment: How does this compare, cpu wise to the standard for loop?

Comment: @GONeale: I haven't done any benchmarks on it. I expect it to be rather lightweight, but the straight for-loop is probably slightly more efficient (no delegates/lambdas for instance). Difference should be neglectable though, unless the code is executed *a lot*.